# How I can throttle only the POST method in this views

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, throttling, api-throttling

```
class ExampleView(APIView):
    throttle_classes = [UserRateThrottle]

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        content = {
            'status': 'request was permitted'
        }
        return Response(content)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        content = {
            'status': 'request was permitted'
        }
        return Response(content)
```

> I want to throttle only the post method view not the get.
> I have declared two views POST and GET and I want only to implement throttling for my POST view

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, this overrides the get_throttles method and does not include throttles for POST method.

```py
class ExampleView(APIView):
    throttle_classes = [UserRateThrottle]

    def get_throttles(self):
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            return []
        return super().get_throttles()

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        content = {
            'status': 'request was permitted'
        }
        return Response(content)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        content = {
            'status': 'request was permitted'
        }
        return Response(content)
```

Comment: Could you please provide me with the complete structure for the class view?

Comment: I have edited my response. Check now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
from rest_framework.decorators import throttle_classes
from rest_framework.throttling import UserRateThrottle

class ExampleView(APIView):

    @throttle_classes([UserRateThrottle])
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        content = {
            'status': 'request was permitted'
        }
        return Response(content)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        content = {
            'status': 'request was permitted'
        }
        return Response(content)
```

Comment: no its not working and i want to add throttling to POST method

Answer (score 0):

By default, `throttle_classes` throttles all methods. If you want to limit it to only throttle the `POST` method in your Django view you need to change the `get_throttles` method by modifying `get_throttles`, you can choose which methods to throttle.

Try this:

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.throttling import UserRateThrottle

class ExampleView(APIView):
    # No need to declare throttle_classes here

    def get_throttles(self):
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            # Apply throttling only for POST requests
            return [UserRateThrottle()]
        return []  # Return an empty list for other methods

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        content = {
            'status': 'GET request was permitted'
        }
        return Response(content)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        content = {
            'status': 'POST request was permitted'
        }
        return Response(content)
```

Here the `get_throttles` method is overridden to apply the `UserRateThrottle` only to `POST` requests.
It returns an empty list for `GET` requests, meaning no throttling will be applied for this request and it will remain unaffected.